# Postgresql - Union table values from different schemas in a database into one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

[image: Table details]

I have a Database called Knowledge in postgres. It has multiple schemas and every schema has same number of tables, table has same columns as well.
Now I want to create a new schema called **Aggregate**, table called aggregate.table1 and put values from schema1.table1 and schema2.table1 in it.

- I need to add another column in Aggregate.table1 which holds the value representing  schema.
- If any value in schema1.table1 is updated then aggregate.table1 should get the updated values.

Question,
Is it possible in Postgresql? if so please help me with this.
*I need this aggregated table for further processing*

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing an `anonymous code block` to iterate over all schemas and tables, so that you can import your data into the aggregate schema. The following block search for all tables contained in the schemas `s1` and `s2`, creates a corresponding table in the schema `s_agg` and finally copies its records.

```
DO $$
DECLARE row record;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname IN ('s1','s2') LOOP
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS s_agg.'||quote_ident(row.tablename)||
      ' AS TABLE ' || quote_ident(row.schemaname)||'.'|| quote_ident(row.tablename) || 
      ' WITH NO DATA;';
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO s_agg.' || quote_ident(row.tablename) 
     || ' SELECT * FROM '||quote_ident(row.schemaname)||'.'||quote_ident(row.tablename);
 END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

**Demo**

```
CREATE SCHEMA s1;
CREATE SCHEMA s2;
CREATE SCHEMA s_agg;

CREATE TABLE s1.t1 (id int);
INSERT INTO s1.t1 VALUES (1);

CREATE TABLE s2.t1 (id int);
INSERT INTO s2.t1 VALUES (42);
        
DO $$
DECLARE row record;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname IN ('s1','s2') LOOP
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS s_agg.'||quote_ident(row.tablename)||
      ' AS TABLE ' || quote_ident(row.schemaname)||'.'|| quote_ident(row.tablename) || 
      ' WITH NO DATA;';
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO s_agg.' || quote_ident(row.tablename) 
     || ' SELECT * FROM '||quote_ident(row.schemaname)||'.'||quote_ident(row.tablename);
 END LOOP;
END;
$$;

-- contains values of t1 from s1 and s2
SELECT * FROM s_agg.t1;

 id 
----
  1
 42
```

**Note**: This code works with the assumption that the *aggregate schema* is either empty or it has empty tables, otherwise data will be duplicated. If you run this periodically and the size of your tables isn't too large, you can add a `DROP TABLE` before the `CREATE TABLE` statement. To make it work on every commit on all tables of all schemas you have to take a look at `TRIGGERS` or even `logical replication`.

Comment: @Jim_Jones I'm looking for a solution where even delta update on the s1.t1 should update the s_agg.t1. I'm looking for support from Postgresql which does this automatically rather than running it periodically and clearing the table.

Comment: @nandeesh as I mentioned in the end, you need to take a look at `logical replication` and `triggers`

Comment: @nandeesh The code block I posted is part of an old script of mine, but it should give you an idea on how to proceed and the caveats. Another alternative: you could also take a look at `pg_agent` and schedule a job to do it for you periodically, in case it does not need to be in real time.